# How do Chrome extensions like WebPaint work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Reference: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-paint/emeokgokialpjadjaoeiplmnkjoaegng?hl=en

I was looking for chrome extension APIs that I could use to draw "anywhere" on browser. Can anyone shed light on the API or resources to look for?

thanks

Comment: There's no such API. The extension is using standard web technologies such as Canvas. You can inspect and debug the source code of the extension in the built-in browser devtools.

Comment: my guess would be : take a screenshot of the current webpage using chrome apis. then replace the dom with canvas with  screenshot image as its background. you can use canvas apis for that.

Comment: I think I found the answer: http://learnwebgl.brown37.net/11_advanced_rendering/overlays.html  Thanks all